# Conditional Variables в Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows

При запуске программы в Windows XP вылезает окошко с сообщением:

> Точка входа в процедуру `InitializeConditionVariable` не найдена в библиотеке Kernel32.dll.

Чем лечить?

Доступ к коду программы есть, могу написать функцию, реализующую тот же функционал, используя `SetEvent()`. Как сделать, чтобы в зависимости от ОС вызывалась та или иная функция? На мой взгляд, это самое простое решение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделать обертку для condition variable (если ее еще нет), а функцию `InitializeConditionVariable` вызывать через `GetProcAddress`, а если ее нет, использовать аналоги

Правда, как утверждают разработчики Chromium, сделать правильную реализацию CV под WinXP тяжело, и оно будет работать не быстро.
Можете посмотреть [на github](https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/master/base/synchronization/condition_variable_win.cc#L127)

Они используют `GetProcAdress` для получения функций и идиому pimpl для выбора той или иной реализации (для Vista или XP)

Comment: Вот это решение мне нравится, при запуске программы проверить, есть ли функция и использовать либо ее, либо свою. Сейчас попробую реализовать.

Comment: Реализация под XP довольно проста. Я сначала сделал ее, а потом узнал, что уже все есть. Ну а если тормозит, то это уже проблема Windows XP.

Comment: @mikelsv Да нет, если торомозит это ваша проблема

Comment: Я уточню: это проблема того, кто поставил себе XP. А вообще, я не очень понимаю где и что там может тормозить. Я реализовал максимально эффективно и если что-то тормозит, значит так и надо.

Answer (score 6):

`Condition Variable` это новшество, которого нет в XP. Они появились с Vista. Таким образом лечить это можно только хирургически - заменить condition variable на что-то другое, или использовать условную компиляцию - для XP одно, для Vista+ другое. А ещё лучше использовать `std::condition_variable` полностью отказавшись от платформо-зависимого решения.

Comment: Я в курсе, что их в XP нет. Отказаться от плафтормо-зависимого в пользу std зависимого? Не, спасибо, не надо.

Comment: @mikelsv, std это стандартная библиотека, так, на всякий случай.

Answer (score 0):

GetVersion() и в зависимости от возвращаемого значения вызывается тот или иной код. Только вам придется отказаться от импорта InitializeConditionVariable, а вместо этого искать (загружать) DLL, получать из нее адрес нужной функции и вызывать ее. Правда, MS не рекомендует GetVersion() теперь...